# Show Hebrew character during PDF creation with DomPdf in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, pdf, laravel-5.4, dompdf

I apologize for not trying anything.

I want to show Hebrew character in the PDF which is created by [Larave DOMPDF](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf).

I don't know what to do and how to achieve this. I did some search on it but no luck.
this is how I load the PDF file

```
PDF::loadView('pdf', ['leadInfo'=>$leadInfo,'leadByContinent'=>$leadByContinent,'leadByStatus'=>$leadByStatus])
                ->save(public_path().'/leadPdfs/'.$leadPdfName);
```

And the PDF blade file is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<!-- Meta, title, CSS, favicons, etc. -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

</head>
<body>

<table class="lead" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="font-size: 12px; font-family: 'Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif';">
     <thead>
        <tr>
           <th width="10%" style="font-weight: bold;">Date</th>
           <th width="15%" style="font-weight: bold;">Name</th>
           <th width="20%" style="font-weight: bold;">Details</th>
           <th width="10%" style="font-weight: bold;">Contact Origin</th>
           <th width="15%" style="font-weight: bold;">Status</th>
           <th width="10%" style="font-weight: bold;">Comment</th>
           <th width="10%" style="font-weight: bold;">Country</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
     <?php
        foreach($leadInfo as $k=>$v){ 

        $continent = getAllContinentName($v->country);
        if(strtolower($continent) == strtolower("Asia")){
          $backGround = "#FFB300";
        } else if(strtolower($continent) == strtolower("Africa")){
          $backGround = "#FFB300";
        } else if(strtolower($continent) == strtolower("North America")){
          $backGround = "#009792";
        } else if(strtolower($continent) == strtolower("South America")){
          $backGround = "#FF7E00";
        } else if(strtolower($continent) == strtolower("Antarctica")){
          $backGround = "#15E6E8";
        } else if(strtolower($continent) == strtolower("Europe")){
          $backGround = "#0074FF";
        } else if(strtolower($continent) == strtolower("Australia")){
          $backGround = "#05A900";
        } else {
          $backGround = "#FFFFFF";
        }

        if($v->email_status_id == 10){
          $statusBackGround = "#a9d18d";
        } else if($v->email_status_id == 11){
          $statusBackGround = "#ff0000";
        } else if($v->email_status_id == 12){
          $statusBackGround = "#b3c6e7";
        } else if($v->email_status_id == 13){
          $statusBackGround = "#c09200";
        } else if($v->email_status_id == 14){
          $statusBackGround = "#ffff00";
        } else {
          $statusBackGround = "#FFFFFF";
        }

     ?>
        <tr>
           <td> {{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($v->created_date)->formatLocalized('%d %b %Y') }} </td>
           <td>{{ $v->name }}</td>
           <td>{{ mb_substr($v->message, 0, 300) }}</td>
           <td>{{ $v->contact_origin }}</td>
           <td style="color:black; background-color: {{ $statusBackGround }}" >{{ $v->status_name }}</td>
           <td>{{ $v->comment }}</td>
           <td style="color:black; background-color: {{ $backGround }}" >{{ getAllCountryName($v->country) }}</td>
        </tr>
     <?php  } ?>
     </tbody>
  </table>   

</body>
</html>
```

and the result is [image]

For now, it shows `?????` instead of Hebrew Character.

Extra Info: The data in the Database is in the Hebrew language, So I just fetch it and put it in the PDF blade file.

It would be great if anyone suggests me anything on this.

I am using Laravel 5.4.

Comment: Israel is a country which speaks several languages. Are you asking how to output Hebrew characters in your pdfs? Show your code and the html you attempt to render to pdf, including which font you are using (that must support Hebrew glyphs). Show that you at least read up on  the unicode support in dompdf...

Comment: Yes, less knowledge on Israel. Yes, I am trying to show the Hebrew language.

Comment: Okay. 1) Update your question to clarify that you're asking about the Hebrew language, not the country Israel. 2) Update your question and add enough source code for us to reproduce your problem to debug it, including both code and html.

Comment: Added @sisve , Please check

Comment: The obvious issue is that the value for `font-family` is wrong. Have you even read https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/UnicodeHowTo ?

Comment: You are right, the issue was on `font-family`. It worked perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Now write an answer to your question detailing what you did to solve the problem so that other people finding your question in the future knows how it was solved.

Comment: Yes Sure I will do it.

Comment: Using "Israel" as a language is very confusing. Israel is not a language any more than "Swiss", "Canadian" or "South African" is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the issue by replacing the `font-family` value to `firefly, DejaVu Sans, sans-serif` which is described in https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/UnicodeHowTo#load-a-font-supporting-your-characters-into-dompdf.

Because the **DejaVu fonts**, supports a wide range of characters. If the DejaVu fonts do not support your characters in your document any **TrueType** font will work.

Comment: Doesn't your Hebrew letters turn out reversed? i.e םולש instead of שלום

Comment: @rony right....what is the solution?